# C# Resources локализация не работает

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Делаю приложение на WPF. Сделал два .resx файла ресурсов.

- Resources.resx
- Resources.ru.resx

В ru локализованные на русский язык строки, в просто resources - английские, соответственно. В теге `<window>` юзаю атрибут `xmlns:cultural="clr-namespace:RemotionServer.Properties"` и задаю у контролов наполнение соответственно (для лейбла `Content="{x:Static cultural:Resources.ScrollSpeedLabel}"`, например). Когда работаю в вижуал студии всё нормально, вся программа на русском, т.е строки берутся из ru. Как только переношу экзешник на рабочий стол или на другой компьютер, то вся программа на английском. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А файлы ресурсов вы переносите? Если не переносить exe-шник куда либо, а просто запустить его из папки Release/Debug ( не студией) корректно работает?

Comment: Да, если запускаю из Рилиз\Дебаг, то тоже всё нормально локализовано

Comment: Копируйте папку Release/Debug целиком. Он у вас не видит файлы ресурсов. Вернее не целиком, там скорее всего лежат ваши файлы Resources.resx, Resources.ru.resx - скопируйте их вместе с exe файлом.

Comment: Мне нужен просто один экзешник, а Resources делаю как "внедренный ресурс"

Comment: Нет, ресурсы для разных языков должны быть в разных файлах. «Просто один экзешник» не будет работать.

Comment: А как мне тогда расположить файлы ресурсов относительно экзешника?

Comment: Либо в том же каталоге, либо в подкаталоге с названием языка, если мне не изменяет память (например, `ru-RU` для русского).